# How to ignore the @JsonProperty value while using the @RequestBody in controller to map value to DTO

Tags: java, json, spring, data-binding, jackson

I want to MAP my HTTP request parameter value directly to my DTO USING @JsonProperty on the basis of the variable name not by @JsonProperty value. I am not able to map the value to DTO because it's expecting request value according to the JsonProperty name. Is there anyway to disable @JsonProperty value while using the @RequestBody ?

JSON send by frontend:

```
{
"userId":"1",
"payMethod":"payMethod"
}
```

MyDto.class
    public class MyDto{

```
    @JsonProperty(value = user_id, required = true)
    private String userId;


    @JsonProperty(value = BETAALMETHODE, required = true)
    private String payMethod;
//getter setter
   }
```

MyController.class

```
public class MyController{

  @RequestMapping(value = "payment", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public Integer PaymentUpdate(@RequestBody final MyDto myDto) throws JsonProcessingException {

}
```

Comment: If you're not going to use `JsonProperty` why did you define it in the first place?

Comment: @lealceldeiro I am using this property in one different process where i am uploading data by using the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using multiple setter method for that DTO method. For example

```
Payload:
{
"userId":"1",
"payMethod":"payMethod"
}
```

then

MyDto.class public class MyDto{

```
@JsonProperty(value = user_id, required = true)
    private String userId;


    @JsonProperty(value = BETAALMETHODE, required = true)
    private String payMethod;
```

add one more setter relevant to the required variable name in the DTO class.

```
@JsonSetter("specifiedName")
void setUserId(String userId){
     this.userId=userId
}

void setPayMethod(String payMethod){ // Will work for "BETAALMETHODE" variable name
     this.payMethod=payMethod
}
@JsonSetter("payMethod")
void setPayMethod(String payMethod){
     this.payMethod=payMethod
}
```

This will solve your problems and variable payMethod will assign in both the cases.

Comment: Great but you implemented after four month.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JacksonMixin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations) during csv parsing:

```
public abstract class MyDtoMixin {
    @JsonProperty(value = user_id, required = true)
    private String userId;

    @JsonProperty(value = BETAALMETHODE, required = true)
    private String payMethod;
}


ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // or CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
mapper.addMixInAnnotations(MyDto.class, MyDtoMixin.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but in this case, I have to create two DTO and I am avoiding this. :)